# How to use the same connection when web scraping with Python?

Tags: python, webkit, screen-scraping

I would like to scrape some information from a webpage at regular intervals. Intervals that would most likely get my IP banned. It was suggested that I use WebKit such as Ghost.py to scrape the data but keeps the connection open simulating an open tab in a browser. I know very little about WebKit, could someone confirm for me that Ghost.py is capable of reusing the same connection, or if there are any other preferred suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PySocks to scrape through a running instance of Tor.

There are some examples of doing this in the book "Web Scraping with Python" (which, full disclosure, I wrote)

Basic scraping through Tor: https://github.com/REMitchell/python-scraping/blob/master/chapter14/1-socks.py

Scraping with Selenium (in case you need to execute JavaScript, or someting like that): https://github.com/REMitchell/python-scraping/blob/master/chapter14/2-seleniumSocks.py

Comment: Ryan, thanks for this, I'm already using PySocks and Tor currently as an alternative to using WebKit, however my impression was that all this does is use an IP address of a tor exit node. My concern is that I need to be scraping the data I require on a second by second basis, and if I dont change the tor identity I risk getting the IP of the exit node banned, which I also want to avoid. Currently i've implement the stem module to alter the exit node ip address after so many requests, however it doesnt quite keep up with the performance I require.

Comment: I voted for the above answer, as I believe Selenium has resolved the problem I was experiencing. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

So this doesn't answer your question regarding 'same connection scraping,' but I'm currently building a web scraper myself using Scrapy.
It's a fast and extensible python framework for scraping the web. I would head to their website and run through the tutorial to see if it fits your needs.

http://scrapy.org/

They also have some common practices that will help you avoid getting banned.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned